# Sorting records in a 1:n (one-to-many) relationship

Tags: sql, mysql, orm, entity-relationship, one-to-many

I've got 2 tables:

```
+-----------+  +------------------------------------+--------------+
+ persons   |  | photos                                            |
+-----------|  +---------------------------------------------------+
+ id | name +  | id | person_id | path              | title        |
+-----------+  +---------------------------------------------------+
+  1 | Tom  +  |  1 |         2 | ~fred/me.png      | Yo, it's Me! |
+  2 | Fred +  |  2 |         2 | ~fred/my_wife.png | I'm Susan    |
+  3 | Jack +  |  3 |         1 | ~tom/my_dog.jpg   | a woof       |
+-----------+  +---------------------------------------------------+
```

which has are in this relationship:

> Person hasMany Photo <-> Photo belongsTo Person

I'd like to list all the persons with their photos (even if someone does not have one, like Jack) and order by photos' title.

**What SQL query (MySQL) should I write for this? Can I use joins in a one-to-many relationship?**

PS: Just as an information, I'd like to be able to construct a such array with the records:

```
$persons = Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => 1,
        [name] => 'Tom',
        [Photo] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [id] => 3,
                [person_id] => 1,
                [path] => '~tom/my_dog.jpg',
                [title] => 'a woof'             // 1st
            )
        )
    ),
    [1] => Array(
        [id] => 2,
        [name] => 'Fred',
        [Photo] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [id] => 2,
                [person_id] => 2,
                [path] => '~fred/my_wife.png',
                [title] => "I'm Susan"          // 2nd
            ),
            [0] => Array(
                [id] => 1,
                [person_id] => 2,
                [path] => '~fred/me.png',
                [title] => "Yo, it's Me!"       // 3rd
            )
        )
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        [id] => 3,
        [name] => 'Jack',
        [Photo] => Array()
    )
)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select *
From persons 
left outer join photos on person.id=photos.person_id
order by photos.title
```